# Monitoring MySQL running within a docker container?

Tags: mysql, docker

I am running mysql (percona) within a docker container. Our normal operations are fine, but once in a while when using it with 1000s of insert operations consecutively, my db connection is lost is and results in my application crash.

How do I monitor the mysql instance running inside the docker container? What solutions are available to me? Ideally, I would like to monitor mysql from the host environment, see the logs and notice when we hit an application error.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where is that error being generated / reported?  That is, by what software?  It isn't an error with which I'm familiar, and Googling for it returns only this question—which suggests to me it might be generated by your application code, in which case it would be useful to know the circumstances in which your application generates such a message...

Comment: @eggyal that was an application error. Right now, I can only see that it is thrown when the application loses connection to db. I will get the exact from MySQL log when I encounter it again. Still any suggestions based on the corrected description?

Answer (score 1):

You can collect logs from container's output: `docker logs -f container_id`

Or even run bash inside this container and work as you want: `docker exec -it container_id bash`